# How can I solve the 'ValueError: putmask: output array is read-only' error when creating a sparse matrix using pandas?

Tags: pandas, numpy, sparse-matrix

I want to create the rating matrix using the Movielens dataset and for that i have to create the sparse matrix.

```
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype
from scipy import sparse

users = df["userId"].dropna().unique()
movies = df["title"].dropna().unique()
shape = (len(users), len(movies))

# Create indices for users and movies
user_cat = CategoricalDtype(categories=sorted(users), ordered=True)
movie_cat = CategoricalDtype(categories=sorted(movies), ordered=True)
user_index = df["userId"].astype(user_cat).cat.codes
movie_index = df["title"].astype(movie_cat).cat.codes
user_index[user_index<0] = 0

# Conversion via COO matrix
coo = sparse.coo_matrix((df["rating"], (user_index, movie_index)), shape=shape)
csr = coo.tocsr()
```

I am currently getting this error when running my code.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3802, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3801 try:
-> 3802     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3803 except KeyError as err:

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx:138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx:144, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

TypeError: '0           False
1           False
2           False
3           False
4           False
            ...  
20000792    False
20000793    False
20000794    False
20000795    False
20000796    False
Length: 20000797, dtype: bool' is an invalid key

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidIndexError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:1105, in Series.__setitem__(self, key, value)
   1104 try:
-> 1105     self._set_with_engine(key, value)
   1106 except KeyError:
   1107     # We have a scalar (or for MultiIndex or object-dtype, scalar-like)
   1108     #  key that is not present in self.index.

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:1175, in Series._set_with_engine(self, key, value)
   1174 def _set_with_engine(self, key, value) -> None:
-> 1175     loc = self.index.get_loc(key)
   1177     # this is equivalent to self._values[key] = value

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3809, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3805 except TypeError:
   3806     # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise
   3807     #  InvalidIndexError. Otherwise we fall through and re-raise
   3808     #  the TypeError.
-> 3809     self._check_indexing_error(key)
   3810     raise

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:5925, in Index._check_indexing_error(self, key)
   5922 if not is_scalar(key):
   5923     # if key is not a scalar, directly raise an error (the code below
   5924     # would convert to numpy arrays and raise later any way) - GH29926
-> 5925     raise InvalidIndexError(key)

InvalidIndexError: 0           False
1           False
2           False
3           False
4           False
            ...  
20000792    False
20000793    False
20000794    False
20000795    False
20000796    False
Length: 20000797, dtype: bool

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[210], line 13
     11 user_index = df["userId"].astype(user_cat).cat.codes
     12 movie_index = df["title"].astype(movie_cat).cat.codes
---> 13 user_index[user_index<0] = 0
     15 # Conversion via COO matrix
     16 coo = sparse.coo_matrix((df["rating"], (user_index, movie_index)), shape=shape)

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:1162, in Series.__setitem__(self, key, value)
   1159 # otherwise with listlike other we interpret series[mask] = other
   1160 #  as series[mask] = other[mask]
   1161 try:
-> 1162     self._where(~key, value, inplace=True)
   1163 except InvalidIndexError:
   1164     # test_where_dups
   1165     self.iloc[key] = value

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:9733, in NDFrame._where(self, cond, other, inplace, axis, level)
   9728 if inplace:
   9729     # we may have different type blocks come out of putmask, so
   9730     # reconstruct the block manager
   9732     self._check_inplace_setting(other)
-> 9733     new_data = self._mgr.putmask(mask=cond, new=other, align=align)
   9734     result = self._constructor(new_data)
   9735     return self._update_inplace(result)

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py:410, in BaseBlockManager.putmask(self, mask, new, align)
    407     align_keys = ["mask"]
    408     new = extract_array(new, extract_numpy=True)
--> 410 return self.apply(
    411     "putmask",
    412     align_keys=align_keys,
    413     mask=mask,
    414     new=new,
    415 )

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py:352, in BaseBlockManager.apply(self, f, align_keys, ignore_failures, **kwargs)
    350         applied = b.apply(f, **kwargs)
    351     else:
--> 352         applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
    353 except (TypeError, NotImplementedError):
    354     if not ignore_failures:

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py:1021, in Block.putmask(self, mask, new)
   1019 try:
   1020     casted = np_can_hold_element(values.dtype, new)
-> 1021     putmask_without_repeat(values.T, mask, casted)
   1022     return [self]
   1023 except LossySetitemError:

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\array_algos\putmask.py:95, in putmask_without_repeat(values, mask, new)
     93         raise ValueError("cannot assign mismatch length to masked array")
     94 else:
---> 95     np.putmask(values, mask, new)

File <__array_function__ internals>:180, in putmask(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: putmask: output array is read-only
```

How can i create the rating matrix using the Movielens dataset? Is the dataset too large that is causing major problems or are there some other errors?

Also please explain or code using latest pandas because code on many articles is not working.

Can i create this using pivot table method of pandas? If so, how?

Comment: It's all in pandas - problem accessing either columns or rows.  A keyerror suggests a bad column name.  But it's hard from the traceback to tell just which dataframe acess is giving problems.  You haven't got anywhere close to making the sparse matrix.

Comment: The problem is in the `user_index[user_index<0]` selection.

Comment: If I don't do  `  user_index[user_index<0] = 0 ` then it gives negative indices

Comment: I'm not saying you shouldn't be doing that.  All I was deducing was there is something wrong in that step.  Maybe some bad value in the column?  I don't have your data so can't reproduce or solve the issue.